# How to install Billreminder 0.4.0?

Tags: package-management

I would like to try the program [Billreminder 0.4.0](http://billreminder.gnulinuxbrasil.org/).  But I need a little help with installing it.  There doesn't seem to be a .deb package available in the software center or Synaptic.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be right. There is no packages in Ubuntu and they don't appear to have any available for download either. That means you'll have to do it yourself. It may sound complicated, but it really isn't. You will have to read a couple of pages, though: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware

Basically: (the above page explains all of this in detail)

1. Install some required tools.
2. Download and extract the compressed file from their site: [billreminder-0.4.0.tar.bz2](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/billreminder/0.4/billreminder-0.4.0.tar.bz2)
3. Run a script to configure the software.
4. Run a script to compile the software.
5. Run a script to package and install the software.

Comment: BilReminder has a Git repository at https://github.com/omaciel/billreminder. Besides, it's very difficult to install it on Ubuntu, since there's some problems with dependencies who is already installed, but autogen.sh doesn't find.